# Dynamically create form rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have severals buttons on a page and depending on the button that is clicked, I want to display a modal view with a specific form.

My thoughts: 1) I could generate a modal form for every button. But I will likely have many buttons, so this will become inefficient quickly. 2) I could some how create the form after the button is pressed with javascript. Is this possible with rails? I want to use the form_tag and pass in the object or it's id based on the button that was clicked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First put each form view in a different partial(_form1.html.erb,_form2.html.erb,_form3.html.erb).
Make each button from your view send a Unobtrusive(http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) request to the controller with a parameter for which form you want to render. Then in the .js.erb file you decide which form is rendered depending on the paremeter sent from the button and then append this form to the modal

**my_view.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Render Form1", my_controller_my_method_path(:form => "_form1",:object_type => "Object1",:object_id => '100'),:remote => true %>
<%= link_to "Render Form2", my_controller_my_method_path(:form => "_form2",:object_type => "Object2",:object_id => '144'),:remote => true %>
<%= link_to "Render Form2", my_controller_my_method_path(:form => "_form3",:object_type => "Object3",:object_id => '160'), :remote => true %>
<div id="#my_modal"></div>
```

**my_controller.rb**

```
def my_method
  @form_partial=params[:form]
  @object=params[:object_type].constantize.find(params[:object_id])
  respond_to  do |format|
   format.js{render :action=>:my_method}
  end
end
```

**my_method.js.erb**

```
$('#my_modal').html("<%= j render :partial => @form_partial %>");
```

**_form1.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag @object do |form| =>
<%= form.input :name%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send a remote request to one of the action on button click where you pass values deciding modal view as comment and the render the corresponding view inside modal using remote js

Comment: So I would request the html from an AJAX request after a button is pressed?

Comment: Thats your choice you may directly use script or you may ask for html and then get it appended in ajax::success event

Comment: Mina Jaki has given the solution